# Cygwin showing error iostream.h is unable to locate

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I wanted to run C programs on windows in order to achieve this I downloaded cygwin(Linux like environment for windows) made a program and kept it on a directory called ..\cygwin\home\Computer

Code goes here

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main(){
printf("Hai");
}
```

When i am trying to execute this program using command prompt.
$ g++ hai.c
Its throwing out an error

```
hai.c:1:21: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 #include<iostream.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

What is going on any idea?

Comment: I don't think you need the `.h`. Try `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: iostream is a C++ header, not C... and for `printf` you need stdio.h.

Comment: @Dmitri It's `iostream.h` which is indicative of a Turbo C/C++ compiler.

Comment: @remyabel i stored the program in c extension.

Comment: @arunwebber you can't use C++ features in a C program.

Comment: `void main()` is illegal in C++ and undefined behavior in C.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant yes.  I got the answer.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, you should first decide which one you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    printf("Hai");
}
```

or with `g++ -x c hai.c` or `gcc hai.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Hai");
}
```